# ReactJS - How to add/use a bootstrap classes?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm

In react app, how can I add and use bootstrap classes without installing it? Is it possible to use bootstrap without install? If yes then how can I use it?

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add bootstrap using Bootstrap CDN. There are three ways to add bootstrap to your react project

1. using Bootstrap CDN
2. installing Bootstrap
3. adding react-bootstrap package

You have to add these lines in your code

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

For more details, check on this links https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/adding-bootstrap-to-react-js-project

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap in ReactJS using the [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) package. But according to your question, it seems like you don't want to install any additional packages. This is also possible if you look at the [Browser Globals](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#browser-globals) section of their documentation. I suggest you use the package rather than the browser globals, it won't add much to your build.

Links:

- [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)
- [React Bootstrap Browser Globals](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#browser-globals)